# footnote in the figure caption (through \footnotetext , footnotemark) does not appear in the same page as the figure

Tags: floats, footnotes

I have several figures in my thesis which need a footnote in their caption. However, I could not find an efficient way to do it looking into the others' inquiries in the forum. In fact, using the `\footnotetext` , `\footnotemark` as the following code, makes the footnote to be appeared in the page before the float. I tried some suggestions such as the minipage, `\clearpage`, etc., to adjust the problem, but they did not work. Anyone could help me? Would appreciate it!

```
\begin{figure}
 \centerline{\includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{./chapter2/Figures/couche2.png}}
 \caption{Lithostratigraphic profile of clay \protect\footnotemark.}
 \label{fig:couche2}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{Lithostratigraphic ....}
```

Comment: Try to add `float` package and place `[H]` in front of  `figure` environment 
`\begin{figure}[H]`

Comment: @salimbou Not even the original creator of `H` recommend using this :)

Comment: It does not work like this, it put the figure at the end of Chapter!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I always used it and always work with me?

Comment: @salimbou The onjection is not that it won't work. The problem is exactly that it does :) Suppressing flotation and leaving manual positioning to the user can produce undesired results, specially if it's done for many floats. Perhaps in a few situations it might be used.

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution with [`afterpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) package.

From the manual

> This package implements a command, \afterpage, that causes the
>   commands specified in its argument to be expanded after the current
>   page is output.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\begin{document} 
\chapter{chapter one} 
\lipsum[1-3]

\afterpage{%
 \begin{figure}
 \centerline{\includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{example-image-a}}
 \caption{Lithostratigraphic profile of clay\protect\footnotemark.}
 \label{fig:couche2}
 \end{figure}
 \footnotetext{Lithostratigraphic ....}
}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It appears not to be the solution for my case either. Using \afterpage, it did not solve the problem, and in addition, it moved the corresponding figure be appeared after its subsequent one in the compiled document!